# Error missing amdgpu firmware

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, amd-graphics, radeon, firmware

My laptop has ATI Radeon Xpress 200M graphics and has an AMD Turion65 processor but apparently incorrect amdgpu drivers are installed. How do I remove them and install the correct drivers?

This is a recent fresh install of Lubuntu 22.10 on an old Gateway MX6440 laptop which has 1TB IDE SSD and 2GB RAM which is the max available for it.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Lubuntu 22.10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely the incorrect drivers are installed as most drivers are modules which are called as needed during startup.

ATI was purchased by AMID is 2006, and rebranded the GPU chipsets to AMD.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/amdgpu-installation may be useful to you.   Also, https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation - it looks like there are both open source and proprietary drivers to choose from.

Also, you might want to update the post and advise the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1293071)

Comment: @ArturMeinild What essential parts did I not provide?  I put to you the question was generic in nature - it did not specify the version of XUbuntu, nor the details of the error.  I answered the specific questions posed and put links to supporting information - not sure what else could reasonably be expected from a generic question.

Comment: You're right, the question doesn't really stand up either.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think or consider you have the wrong drivers? What are you basing that on? What's the output of `lsmod` & `glxinfo`?

Please be in mind that there are two drivers for that card:

1. Proprietary from AMD (ex ATI). It was called fglrx and it will not work on Ubuntu 22. IIRC the last supported version was either 14.04 or 16.04
2. Open Source. It's included in the kernel so it should work automatically. I don't know how good it is since it's a very old GPU. It may be possible that it's not being packed with Ubuntu's kernel build. If that's the case you'd have to build the kernel yourself.